# Adobe Air vs Java for Internet Cafe Time Manager Application

Tags: java, apache-flex, air, desktop-application

I'm planning to do a little project to expand my knowledge in programming. The application I'm trying to build is an Internet Cafe Manager (I Know there are a lot software out there that is similar to what I'm building.). I had chosen this project since it involves connecting to a network, displaying data and time, and has a client and server version of the application.

Now I wan't to get your opinion on what language and approach do you prefer for me to use. I am thinking I will be using  Air or Flex since I have a some experience with flash and I am also a fan of good interfaces of AIR/Flex. Also I am thinking that there maybe some read AIR application I can integrate to rapid my development. Java is also in my list, Two of my programmer friend suggest that I will go for Java, But I don't have any background on java.

What Do you think? Please let me know your opinion.

Thank You!

Comment: What will be their reason(s) to use java? Because it is related to coffee (hence cafe)? :P

Comment: My friends suggested different languages and their own reasons, It just happen that 2 of my friends suggested JAVA that I also want to learn and expand in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a subjective question but it really depends on what you are most comfortable with. Personally, I feel that the tools for Flex/AIR development are much easier to get started with the those of Java. This is especially true if you are taking about using an IDE for Flex development. Using the Flex framework could definitely allow you to get more done quickly.

Just my opinion.

Java is definitely a useful language but can be a big pill to swallow if you are just starting out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I also think that if I would start on java it would be a hard start for me.